# Octave + BLAS + ACML and a lot of confusion

Tags: octave, gfortran, blas

I tried to compile Octave and got the popular message about not compatibility of gfortran with BLAS. I checked the config.log file and extracted the failed test program, to test it separately. Indeed, the test failed. Now, this gets confused - at least for me:

1. The test program (added at the bottom) is not compiled (in configure) with the compiler option which forces gfortran into 64-bit default mode, and the integers used inside are declared as simple integer (not *8). So, if this has to work with 64-bit integer mode, should I make a version of gfortran with 64 bit integer default (I read that all fortrans should use integer*4 by default.
2. I tested gfortran with 64-bit integers, declaring an integer*8, and printing huge() of that integer - it did print the 64-bit huge number, so, at least 'manually', gfortran seems ok.
3. Tried to compile octave with --enable-64 --with-blas=acml_mp --with-lapack=acml_mp and get:
   "BLAS doesn't seem to support 64-bit integers"
4. libgfortran doesn't seem to be linked to blas (checked with ldd). Why are they fighting at all? Do I have to recompile libgfortran?

I'd rather know why this is happening than just a quick recipe (though that'd be welcome too), so a pointer to some applicable docs would be helpful!

This is the test program - I can't get gfortran to agree with libblas (which points to libacml):

```
   program main

c  Compile with:
c  fortran -o testblas -ff2c -ff2c   testblas.f -lblas -lm -ffixed-line-length-none

   integer n,nn(3)
   real s,a(1),b(1),sdot
   b(1) = 1.0
   a(1) = 1.0
   print *, "Generate -2**32 + 1, if possible, to check if gfortran is 32/64 bit"
   print *, "If N >= 0, we are on 32 bits"                                       
   n = 2
   n = -4 ** (n ** 30)
   n = n + 1
   print*, "N=", n
   if (n >= 0) goto 1
   print *, "This means we are on 64-bit integers. Check whether the BLAS is, too."
   s = sdot(n,a,1,b,1)
   print *, "S should be <> 0: "
   if (s .ne. 0.0) stop 1
1  continue
   print*, "We may be on 32-bit integers, and the BLAS on 64 bits. This is almost bound"
   print*, "to have already failed, but just in case, we'll check."
   nn(1) = -1
   nn(2) = 1
   nn(3) = -1
   s = sdot(nn(2),a,1,b,1)
   print*, "BLAS, if 32-bit, will make s 1, and all is ok: s=", s
   if (s .ne. 1.0) stop 1                                        

   end
```

The output here was:

```
Generate -2**32 + 1, if possible, to check if gfortran is 32/64 bit
 If N >= 0, we are on 32 bits
 N=           1
 We may be on 32-bit integers, and the BLAS on 64 bits. This is almost bound
 to have already failed, but just in case, we'll check.
 BLAS, if 32-bit, will make s 1, and all is ok: s=   0.00000000    
STOP 1
```